# Как в kivy python сделать проверку нажата ли кнопка?

Tags: python, kivy

Как в kivy python сделать проверку нажата ли кнопка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы выполнить действие по нажатию кнопки, можно `on_press` параметр указать при её создании:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(
            text="Нажми на меня",
            on_press=lambda b: print('Кнопка <{b.text}> нажата'.format(**vars())))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Ещё можно [через `.bind()` метод с `on_press` либо `state` параметрами](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html) или в Kv разметке:

```
Button:
  text: 'Нажми на меня'
  on_press: self.text = 'Нажали'
```